# How to get everything between tags

Tags: php

I have the following string

```
Something {{ another thing. You can use html code also, eg: <b>hello</b>}}
```

I'm using the following RegEx to replace the string after `Something`

```
$description = preg_replace(
    '/{{(.*)}}/i', '$2', $desc
);
```

The output is: Something

Works fine.

I'm using Wysyng Editor, the user can use that expression, so the system must to separate according above code.

There are two trouble:

If user type something like it doesn't works

```
Something

{{
    Another text
}}
```

The second trouble. The editor generates above expression like that

```
<p>Something</p>
<p>{{</p>
    Another Text
<p>}}</p>
```

I'm using `strip_tags` to get the real string. There are a way to do it?

Comment: Simply take a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php  There is a "MULTILINE" modifier.

Comment: @arkascha The m / MULTILINE modifier only affects ^ and $ anchoring. This is about making `.` match newlines as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `.` match a newline in a string, you have to use the `s` modifier:

> **s (PCRE_DOTALL)**
>
> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.

So to add `s` to your list of modifiers:

```
preg_replace('/{{(.*)}}/is', '$2', $desc);
```

The `i` modifier (case insensitive`) doesn't really do anything useful either, as you're only matching special characters.

I'd also suggest modifying `.*` to `.*?`, so that you don't end up matching the ending `}}` of a replacement further down in the text.

For your second case, I'd check if the substring starts with and ends with the tags you're expecting, then remove them - and error out otherwise. Using `strip_tags` may remove a whole lot more that you actually expect to be present, depending on your use case.

Comment: Nice! It's Working for first scenery. My second scenerey i need the tags, because the user can use tags between {{ }}. I'll try make a logic based in your example. Thanks;